# Update one JSON array element with a second JSON based on third JSON with jq

Tags: json, dictionary, merge, jq

I have four files:

input.json

```
{
  ".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection": {
    "type": "collection",
    "value": [
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan",
        "plan_description": "my-plan",
        "account_name": "vault-supplied-value"
        "account_access_key": "vault-supplied-value"
      },
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan-test",
        "plan_description": "my-plan-test",
        "account_name": "vault-supplied-value",
        "account_access_key": "vault-supplied-value"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false
  }
}
```

vault.json

```
{
  "appd": {
    "account_key": "appd-key",
    "account_name": "appd-user"
  },
  "aws": {
    "access_key_id": "my-key-id",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "secret_access_key": "my-secret-key"
  }
}
```

keyfile.json

```
[
  [[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value[0]", "account_name"], ["appd", "account_name"]],
  [[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value[0]", "account_access_key"], ["appd", "account_key"]],
  [[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value[1]", "account_name"], ["appd", "account_name"]],
  [[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value[1]", "account_access_key"], ["appd", "account_key"]]
]
```

valut.jq

```
reduce $keyfile[] as $p (.; setpath(($p|.[0]); $vault|getpath($p|.[1])))
```

This is my jq command:

```
jq --argfile keyfile keyfile.json --argfile vault vault.json -f vault.jq input.json > desired.json
```

desired.json

```
{
  ".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection": {
    "type": "collection",
    "value": [
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan",
        "plan_description": "my-plan",
        "account_name": "appd-key",
        "account_access_key": "appd-user"
      },
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan-test",
        "plan_description": "my-plan-test",
        "account_name": "appd-key",
        "account_access_key": "appd-user",
        "controller_host": "example.com"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false
  }
}
```

I'm not coding the keyfile.json file correctly, because I am not getting the desired results.
I've tried every iteration of the keyfile.json I can think of, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

what-i-get.json

```
{
  ".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection": {
    "type": "collection",
    "value": [
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan",
        "plan_description": "my-plan",
        "account_name": "vault-supplied-value",
        "account_access_key": "vault-supplied-value"
      },
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan-test",
        "plan_description": "my-plan-test",
        "account_name": "vault-supplied-value",
        "account_access_key": "vault-supplied-value"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "value[0]": {
      "account_name": "appd-user",
      "account_access_key": "appd-key"
    },
    "value[1]": {
      "account_name": "appd-user",
      "account_access_key": "appd-key"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you adapt the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954791 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's just the syntax used in your keyfile - It is causing a string literal `"value[0]"` to be created instead of the array index 0 being referenced in the path substitution.

**Try use the syntax**

```
"value",0,"account_name"
```

**Instead of**

```
"value[0]","account_name"
```

Using the below as `keyfile.json`:

```
[
  [["properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value",0, "account_name"], ["appd", "account_name"]],
  [["properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value",0, "account_access_key"], ["appd", "account_key"]],
  [["properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value",1, "account_name"], ["appd", "account_name"]],
  [["properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection", "value",1, "account_access_key"], ["appd", "account_key"]]
]
```

Produces desired.json:

```
{
  ".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection": {
    "type": "collection",
    "value": [
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan",
        "plan_description": "my-plan",
        "account_name": "appd-user",
        "account_access_key": "appd-key"
      },
      {
        "plan_name": "my-plan-test",
        "plan_description": "my-plan-test",
        "account_name": "appd-user",
        "account_access_key": "appd-key"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false
  }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:**
If it helps, the way I came across the proper syntax after some headscratching was to view the output as a stream in compact format:

```
jq -c '. | tostream' input.json
```

```
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","optional"],false]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","type"],"collection"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",0,"account_access_key"],"vault-supplied-value"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",0,"account_name"],"vault-supplied-value"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",0,"plan_description"],"my-plan"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",0,"plan_name"],"my-plan"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",0,"plan_name"]]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1,"account_access_key"],"vault-supplied-value"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1,"account_name"],"vault-supplied-value"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1,"plan_description"],"my-plan-test"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1,"plan_name"],"my-plan-test"]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1,"plan_name"]]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value",1]]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection","value"]]
[[".properties.on_demand_service_plans_collection"]]
```

Comment: The one iteration I did not try! Thank you @hmedia1 for this perfect answer.